# How to make custom view like this

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

[image: enter image description]

I want to make view like this, is any library available for make this type view.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create your own View.
Extend `View` class and implement `onDraw` method.

```
class CustomView extends View {
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // using canvas you can draw anything you want
  }
// [...]
```

You can find more information about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components